# In a loop, optionally write output to files

Tags: python, output

I wrote a function which iteratively computes some quantities `X,Y`, returning the final result. Additionally, this code saves each iteration of `X,Y` to a file. Here is the basic structure:

```py
def myFunc():
    X,Y = 0,0
    file1 = open(output1,"w")
    file2 = open(output2,"w")
    for i in range(1000):
        X,Y = someCalculation(X,Y) #calculations happen here
        file1.write(X)
        file2.write(Y)
    file1.close()
    file2.close()
    return X,Y
```

However, if the filename `output1` or `output2` is omitted when the function is called, I need this function to perform the same calculation **without appending anything to the relevant file**.

Here is my messy solution:

```py
def myFunc(output1=None,output2=None):
    X,Y = 0,0
    if (output1 != None): file1 = open(output1,"w")
    if (output2 != None): file2 = open(output2,"w")
    for i in range(1000):
        X,Y = someCalculation(X,Y) #calculations happen here
        if (output1 != None): file1.write(X)
        if (output2 != None): file2.write(Y)
    if (output1 != None): file1.close()
    if (output2 != None): file2.close()
    return X,Y
```

Is there a better, cleaner way to write this?

Comment: I think this is basically the best you can do, with perhaps slight improvements like using `if output1` instead of `if output1 != None`.

Comment: Unrelated, but variable and function names in Python are generally written in `snake_case`, not `camelCase`.

Comment: Now that I think about it, simply using `/dev/null` as the filename should work on Linux and Mac.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thanks, I didn't know about `/dev/null`. But an unnecessary write in every iteration (when no output files are specified) would slow down my code significantly...I might as well write to a default file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a dummy file object that ignores writes, and supports the context manager interface:

```
class NoFile:
    def __enter__(self): return self
    # Propagate any exceptions that were raised, explicitly.
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb): return False
    # Ignore the .write method when it is called.
    def write(self, data): pass
    # We can extend this with other dummy behaviours, e.g.
    # returning an empty string if there is an attempt to read.
```

Make a helper function that creates one of these instead of a normal file when the filename `is None`:

```
def my_open(filename, *args, **kwargs):
    return NoFile() if filename is None else open(filename, *args, **kwargs)
```

Use `with` blocks to manage the file lifetimes, as you should do anyway - but now use `my_open` instead of `open`:

```
def myFunc(output1=None,output2=None):
    X, Y = 0, 0
    with my_open(output1, 'w') as f1, my_open(output2, 'w') as f2:
        for i in range(1000):
            X, Y = someCalculation(X, Y) #calculations happen here
            f1.write(X)
            f2.write(Y)
    return X, Y
```

Comment: Note to self: I have been already working on a project to propose enhancements to the standard library and to builtins. A fully-worked version of this should definitely be included.

Comment: I'll give this a try, thank you. I'm still learning about context managers, but why exactly does \_\_exit\_\_ need to return False? Can't it just pass?

Comment: Struggling to get this code to run: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'`

Comment: Fixed the bug; `__enter__` cannot just pass, as it `returns` the actual thing that will be assigned to the `as` variable. `__exit__` *can* just pass, since `None` is falsey. However, returning `False` is more explicit. The underlying machinery will use the boolean return for `__exit__` to decide whether to re-raise any exceptions that were thrown.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a dummy class that has a do-nothing `write` method. `ExitStack` is used to ensure any opened files are closed automatically.

```
from contextlib import ExitStack


class NoWrite:
    def write(self, value):
        pass


def myFunc(output1=None, output2=None):
    X,Y = 0,0
    with ExitStack() as es:
        file1 = es.enter_context(open(output1, "w")) if output1 is not None else NoWrite()
        file2 = es.enter_context(open(output2, "w")) if output2 is not None else NoWrite()

        for i in range(1000):
            X,Y = someCalculation(X, Y) #calculations happen here
            file1.write(X)
            file2.write(Y)
    return X,Y
```

---

As you appear to be logging the `X` and/or `Y` values at each step, you may want to look into using the `logging` module instead, creating a `FileHandler` for the appropriate logger instead of passing output file names to `myFunc` itself.

```
import logging

# configuration of the logger objects is the responsibility
# of the *user* of the function, not the function itself.
def myFunc():
    x_logger = logging.getLogger("myFunc.x_logger")
    y_logger = logging.getLogger("myFunc.y_logger")

    X,Y = 0,0
    for i in range(1000):
        X,Y = someCalculation(X, Y)
        x_logger.info("%s", X)
        y_logger.info("%s", Y)
    return X,Y
```

Comment: What's the reasoning behind using this over a standard `with ... as` block?

Comment: Because whether you have 0, 1, or 2 file objects to open and close isn't a static property of the function. An exit stack lets you add context managers at runtime based on information that isn't know at compile time.

Comment: but in this code there are definitely exactly two *contexts* to enter and exit. Just that sometimes they'll be the `NoWrite` proxies.

Comment: That would require making `NoWrite` a context manager as well, something I was too lazy to do :) `NoWrite` is *just* file-like enough to support "writing" to a file.

Comment: Ah, right, the `enter_context` magic comes from `ExitStack` in the first place. Honestly I think my approach is more reusable, and minimizes the complication in the client code.

Comment: Making `NoWrite` a context manager is arguably a better solution, but what can I say: I like `ExitStack`, and like to call attention to possible uses for it.

Comment: (I saw that another answer had been posted, but didn't actually get around to refreshing the page to see it until after these comments.)

Answer (score 1):

Simpler: write to a "null device" file defined by your operating system to have no effect when written to.

The standard library `os` module defines a string constant `devnull` which identifies the path to this file: `'/dev/null'` on Mac and Linux, `'NUL'` on Windows (I suppose the latter is not actually a path).

```
import os
def myFunc(output1=os.devnull,output2=os.devnull):
    # as before, with no special conditional logic
```