# Use Conditional within Context Manger

Tags: python, contextmanager

I want to be able to do something like this:

```py
file1 = 'data/f1.txt'
file2 = None
file3 = 'data/f3.txt'
with open(file1) as f1, open(file2) as f2, open(file3) as f3:
    for i in range(1000):
        x,y,z = func(i)
        if f1: f1.write(f"{x}\n")
        if f2: f2.write(f"{y}\n")
        if f3: f3.write(f"{z}\n")
```

So that output is only written to files if paths are provided.

I tried the following:

```py
file1 = 'data/f1.txt'
file2 = None
file3 = 'data/f3.txt'
with open(file1) if file1 else None as f1, open(file2) if file2 else None as f2, open(file3) if file3 else None as f3:
    for i in range(1000):
        x,y,z = func(i)
        if f1: f1.write(f"{x}\n")
        if f2: f2.write(f"{y}\n")
        if f3: f3.write(f"{z}\n")
```

But I got `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType`.

Is there a simple, pythonic way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Extremely similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72756520/in-a-loop-optionally-write-output-to-files/72756581?noredirect=1#comment128511426_72756581.

Comment: some of this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803059/conditional-with-statement-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time you've invented identifiers `file{1,2,3}`,
that's starting to be a Code Smell that you
really want to fill a container with files.

Create a `class FilesWriter` that is a context manager.
Pass in a bunch of filespecs.
It will simply discard any empty ones:

```
    self.fspec_to_file = {}
    for fspec in fspecs:
        if fspec is not None:
            self.fspec_to_file[fspec] = open(fspec, 'w')
```

Now your instance is responsible for closing those
when the `with` calls your `__exit__` method.

In the body of the `with`,
caller will either invoke a `write_to_all(s: str)` method you provide,
or will use the elements of `fspec_to_file` as needed.

So calling sequence would look like:

```
    with FilesWriter([fspec1, fspec2, fspec3]) as fw:
        for i in range(1000):
            result = compute()
            fw.write_to_all(result)
```

and upon leaving the block your `__exit__` method does:

```
    for f in self.fspec_to_file.values():
        f.close()
```

Strictly speaking `.close()` *can* fail, e.g. due to full disk.
Put it in a `try` block if needed.

If any `open()` fails, it might make sense to
close all previously opened files and die
with fatal error.

You seemed to need to know details about each open file.
But if not, feel free to convert that `dict` to
a simple `set` of open file handles.

Comment: This is a very creative solution. Thanks!